# CSS Can I set a higher % width on smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, width, percentage

I set a width of 70% on my , which looks ok, but for mobile screens it wouldn't hurt if the width was higher, say 90%.

So my question is... Is there a way to make the site's width higher percentage if the screen is smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use media query for that:

```
div {
width:70%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    div {
        width:90%;
    }
}
```

[Get a head start on media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Or use a framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Using bootstrap, you can achieve that using:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12">blah blah</div>
```

Comment: This works when I resize a window on my computer but somehow my mobile still shows the 70% width version? I'm guessing since the resolution of my phone is hd?

Comment: I guess so. Try using a value in place of 500 which is higher than the pixel width of your phone.

Comment: Probably 800px to 900px would be a right value for you.

Comment: I tried anything up to 1000px but this doesn't really do what I'm looking for sadly

Comment: Did you try the bootstrap option? I personally never took up the raw media query. I am happy with bootstrap.

Comment: No but honestly, it's not a big deal, I just wondered if there was any simple way. Your answer is good and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

A little light reading on media queries:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

```
.content {
   width: 70%;
 }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
 .content {
   width: 90%;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code will not help him, because after you set the content to 90%, you set it to 70%. You have to to them in the reverse order. First wothout the media query, then using the media query.

Comment: This works when I resize a window on my computer but somehow my mobile still shows the 70% width version? I'm guessing since the resolution of my phone is hd?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your size media query with a resolution media query:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), /* Webkit-based browser */
       (max-width: 600px) and (min-resolution: 2dppx), /* The standard way */            
       (max-width: 600px) and (min-resolution: 192dpi) /* dppx fallback */
```